# How to change the numbering format for citations in text?

Tags: bibtex, citing

I would like to change the numbering for my citations from `[X]` to `[1.X]` throughout the text. I found a way to change `[X]` to `[1.X]` in the bibliography:

```
\renewcommand{\bibnumfmt}[1]{[1.#1]}
```

This changes `[X]` to `[1.X]` throughout the bibliography, but not in the body of the text. How would I change `[X]` to `[1.X]` also within the body of the text?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are using natbib like this:

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
```

If so, just try this:

```
\renewcommand{\bibnumfmt}[1]{[1.#1]}
\makeatletter
\let\cite@orignal\cite
\def\cite{\cite@original[1.\@gobble][]}
\makeatother
```

Explanation: `\@gobble` eats the space between 1. and X.